# NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces() hardware address does not have wlan0 in list

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mac-address, network-interface

I develop 2 mobile apps. First one is in Kotlin, second one is in Java. I use the same code to get MAC address in both. But in Kontlin it works:

```
            val all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces())
        for (nif in all) {
            if (nif.name.contains("wlan") || nif.name.contains("eth")) {

                val macBytes = nif.hardwareAddress ?: return ""

                val res1 = StringBuilder()
                for (b in macBytes) {
                    res1.append(String.format("%02X:", b))
                }

                if (res1.length > 0) {
                    res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length - 1)
                }
                return res1.toString().toUpperCase()
            }
        }
```

Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()) returns 25 items, including wlan0,

but in Java code (the same device)

```
            List<NetworkInterface> all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface nif : all) {
            if (nif.getName().contains("wlan") || nif.getName().contains("eth")) {
                byte[] macBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
                if (macBytes == null) {
                    return "";
                }

                StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
                for (byte b : macBytes) {
                    res1.append(String.format("%02X:", b));
                }

                if (res1.length() > 0) {
                    res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length() - 1);
                }
                mac = res1.toString().toUpperCase();
            }
        }
```

Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()) returns 3 items, with no wlan0, but having swlan, and all of list items hardware addresses are null.
Both apps have permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: both snippet are working on same device?

Comment: All code outputs are from same device. the problem occurs not on all devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think likely the two apps have different target SDK versions. The documentation for `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()` states:

> For non-system apps with targetSdkVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R, this method will only return information for NetworkInterfaces that are associated with an InetAddress.

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface#getNetworkInterfaces()